# password required from rest framework after sending password

Tags: django-rest-framework, backend, django-users

So i want to make a registration system with django rest framework so i can use it with React. Here is my `serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from backApp.models import Client 

class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:

        model = Client 
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'password2']

        extra_kwargs = {

            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

        def save(self):

            client = Client(

                email = self.validated_data['email'], 
                username = self.validated_data['username'],
            )

            password = self.validated_data['password']
            password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
            if password != password2: 

                raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': "password doesn't match"})

            client.set_password(password)
            client.save()

            return client
```

and here is `views.py`

```
from rest_framework import status 
from rest_framework.response import Response 
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework import permissions
from authentication.api.serializers import RegistrationSerializer

@api_view(['POST',])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def registration_view(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        
        if serializer.is_valid():

            client = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = "successfully registred!"
            data['email'] = client.email
            data['username'] = client.username
            
        else: 

            data = serializer.errors 

        return Response(data)
```

when i sent a post request with postman i get the following error:

password: field required
password2: field required

here is my input data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v83oP.png)

So please can you tell me where is the error and how i can fix it ?
Thanks in advance ^^.

Comment: Show your input data from postman.

Comment: @monio i added my input data image in the post, take a look at it please

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass the password field using url, that I figured from your postman snapshot.
Take a look at this image you will find Body tab where you will be able to send data using postman and use post method. This should work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are making post request with params not form/json data. you will understand if you look at the url

Comment: there is not json option in postman